# How to get cursor position in a Chrome DevTools source editor from extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I develop [Open in Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-in-editor/fmgbklepjbpnmgplnabblaehammnbmgg) extension for Google Chrome DevTools that allows to open source file in external editor using context menu.

It works perfectly in most of cases (*Network panel*, *Performance panel*, *Style inspector*, and so on) when file location in UI contains a line number (like `jquery.js:2191`).
The only exception is ***Sources panel***. A [chrome.devtools.panels.setOpenResourceHandler](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels#method-setOpenResourceHandler) callback function doesn't receive a line number.

Does DevTools has some API to get a position of cursor in source editor from `setOpenResourceHandler()` callback?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could check this https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/ and this https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/go-to-a-line-number-at-a-specific-column but there is still no method mention like it. Maybe this is not supported yet as of now.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot, thank you for an advice. I've raised the issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=747888 .

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been explained as per reported [Chrome Issue 747888](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=747888):

> So first of all, `setOpenResourceHandle()` is for the cases when users click a link (e.g. a `linkified` location in console) that normally results in opening a source tab in DevTools, it's not meant to be fired when a file is explicitly opened in the source panel. For changes of the file/position within the sources tab, we've got `chrome.devtools.panels.sources.onSelectionChanged` (see a [layout test](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/LayoutTests/http/tests/devtools/extensions/extensions-events.html?l=47) for example usage) that  was recently brought back by *@jacobr*).

Here is the mentioned code example:

```
function extension_testElementsOnSelectionChanged(nextTest)
{
    function onSelectionChanged()
    {
        webInspector.panels.elements.onSelectionChanged.removeListener(onSelectionChanged);
        output("onSelectionChanged fired");
        nextTest();
    }
    webInspector.panels.elements.onSelectionChanged.addListener(onSelectionChanged);
    webInspector.inspectedWindow.eval("inspect(document.body.children[0]), 0");
}

function extension_testSourcesOnSelectionChangedShowFile(nextTest)
{
    function onSelectionChanged(selectionInfo)
    {
        webInspector.panels.sources.onSelectionChanged.removeListener(onSelectionChanged);
        output("sources onSelectionChanged fired, selectionInfo:");
        dumpObject(selectionInfo, {url: "url"});
        nextTest();
    }
    webInspector.panels.sources.onSelectionChanged.addListener(onSelectionChanged);
    evaluateOnFrontend("InspectorTest.showScriptSource(\"test-script.js\")");
}

function extension_testSourcesOnSelectionChangedShowFileAndLine(nextTest)
{
    webInspector.inspectedWindow.eval("location.href", function(inspectedPageURL) {
        function onSelectionChanged(selectionInfo)
        {
            webInspector.panels.sources.onSelectionChanged.removeListener(onSelectionChanged);
            output("sources onSelectionChanged fired, selectionInfo:");
            dumpObject(selectionInfo, {url: "url"});
            nextTest();
        }
        webInspector.panels.sources.onSelectionChanged.addListener(onSelectionChanged);

        var basePath = inspectedPageURL.replace(/\/[^/]*$/, "/");
        webInspector.panels.openResource(basePath + "resources/test-script.js", 2);
    });
}
```